# How to fix IE 8 whitespace bug for YUI 3.4.1 Tabview?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, yui, yahoo-api

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.  I have some basic markup.  I am using the `reset`, `fonts`, `grids`, and `base` files for `Yahoo User Interface (YUI 3.4.1)`.  When I add a `TabView` to the larger section then there is a space beneath it in `IE 8`.  `FireFox` works fine.  Not sure why it is doing this, can someone please check?  When I remove the outer div then it is fine.

My external css file:

```
body{margin:auto;width:1025px;}
#nav{width:280px;}
#main{width:745px;}
#hd #hd-container{border-bottom:solid 2px #2647a0;margin-bottom:1em;}
#ft #ft-container{border-top:solid 2px #2647a0;text-align:center;}
#ft #ft-container #copyright{margin-bottom:0;}
#hd-container,#ft-container{padding:10px;}
#main-container{}
.main-content{}
```

Here is just a partial markup:

```
<body class="yui3-skin-sam">

    <div id="hd" style="background-color:Aqua;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet metus. Nunc quam elit, posuere nec, auctor in, rhoncus quis, dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut dignissim, massa sit amet dignissim cursus, quam lacus feugiat.
        </div>

        <div id="bd">

            <div class="yui3-g">

                <div class="yui3-u" id="nav" style="background-color:Yellow;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet metus. Nunc quam elit, posuere nec, auctor in, rhoncus quis, dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut dignissim, massa sit amet dignissim cursus, quam lacus feugiat.
                </div>
                <div class="yui3-u" id="main">

                    <div id="main-container"> <-- This div is giving the issue -->
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet metus. Nunc quam elit, posuere nec, auctor in, rhoncus quis, dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut dignissim, massa sit amet dignissim cursus, quam lacus feugiat.
                        <div id="demo">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#foo">foo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#bar">bar</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#baz">baz</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div>
                                <div id="foo">foo content</div>
                                <div id="bar">bar content</div>
                                <div id="baz">baz content</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet metus. Nunc quam elit, posuere nec, auctor in, rhoncus quis, dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut dignissim, massa sit amet dignissim cursus, quam lacus feugiat.
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="ft" style="background-color:Aqua;">
            <div id="ft-container">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet metus. Nunc quam elit, posuere nec, auctor in, rhoncus quis, dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut dignissim, massa sit amet dignissim cursus, quam lacus feugiat.
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            YUI().use('tabview', function (Y) {
                var tabview = new Y.TabView({
                    srcNode: '#demo'
                });

                tabview.render();
            });
        </script>

 </body>
```

Comment: Is there no one that can help replicate this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that IE 8 has white space issues.  Read it here: http://jhop.me/ie8-bugs